# Software Change

Tags: software, customer-service

We are currently going through a software change and will be going live with our new ERP system next month.  We need to inform all of our customers that their orders will need to be adjusted.  Does anyone have any great examples of letters?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be that hard:

> Dear {valued customer name},
>
> We are currently upgrading our business systems in order to make things better for you, our customer.
>
> Unfortunately, because of the upgrade, any orders currently outstanding requirement some adjustment. We will be sending the adjusted orders out to you as soon as possible.
>
> We thank you for your consideration and will work to keep the disruption to a minimum. We look forward to our continued business relationship so that you can take advantage of these upgrades.
>
> Regards,
>
> {your business team}

If there's not going to be any change in pricing on these orders, it would be good to include a statement to that effect, too.

Essentially - people don't mind a bit of change/disruption if it's to their eventual benefit and has no cost in time or money.